# Can you convert a categorical proposition into a zeroth order proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, math-history, philosophy

I am a student learning mathematical logic as a hobby. When I say "zeroth order" I mean "not predicate logic".

**Question:** Is it possible to convert a categorical proposition into a zeroth-order proposition?

For example: If I have a categorical proposition "All $S$ are $P$", then can I construct an implication that says "If an object is $S$, then the object is $P$"?

If this is possible, then is there a specific replacement rule for accomplishing this? Does the replacement depend on whether the categorical proposition is [$A$, $E$,  $I$, or $O$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition#Translating_statements_into_standard_form)?

Comment: Just so you know: these "categorical propositions" are not the kinds of things that are studied in modern mathematical logic (except in the corner of this field that's sometimes called "natural logic"). Talking about A, E, I, and O is likely to confuse people, even experts in logic.

Comment: If you want to avoid explicit quantifiers, you'll need implicit ones, which English provides (in some situations). For example, "If an object is S, then the object is P" expresses a universally quantified statement, without explicitly saying "all" or "every" or "any", because it's understood to refer to arbitrary objects. For a mathematical study, it's much better to make quantifiers explicit, as in predicate logic, because leaving them implicit can lead to ambiguity and unwanted complications.

Answer (score 1):

"All $S$ are $P$" is translated in modern logic exactly as "For every $x$, if $x$ is $S$ then $x$ is $P$", i.e. as $∀x(Sx → Px)$.

[Categorical propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) are part of the theory of [Syllogism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#Syl). In modern terms, it is part of an interesting fragment of predicate logic: the so called [monadic predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus).

But regarding the title question, the answer is: no.

In propositional logic we can have $S → P$ and $S ∧ P$, but we cannot express the difference between "all" and "some".